# How to make a filled and hollow square, placed horizontally next to each other in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my homework I need to create a square and hollow box which the dimensions of which the user chooses by entering an integer. The program would then place these boxes beside one another. Currently it prints the hollow box below the solid box.

```
    dimensions = int(input(">"))
    for row_1 in range (dimensions):
        for col_1 in range (dimensions):
            print (("*"), end="")
        print()

    inner_dimensions = dimensions - 2
    print ('*' * dimensions)
    for i in range(inner_dimensions):
        print ('*' + ' ' * inner_dimensions + '*')
    print ('*' * dimensions)
```

It would produce two boxes made of asterisks, one hollow, one solid horizontal form one another.

Comment: You must include the code for both boxes in a single for-loop over all rows. For the hollow box you must also use an `if` to check for first or last row as these look differently.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, I hope that's what you wanted

```
size = int(input(">"))

for i in range (0,size):
    for j in range (0,2*size+1):
        if((i==0 or i==size-1) and j!=size):
            print("*",end="")
        elif(j==0 or j==size-1 or j>size):
            print("*",end="")
        else:
            print(" ",end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.6 or greater:

```py
size = int(input(">"))
square = ''
square_with_hollow = ''

for i in range (0, size):
    square = '*' * size
    if i in (0, size -1):
        square_with_hollow = '*' * size
    else:
        square_with_hollow = f'*{" " * (size - 2) }*'

    print(f'{square} {square_with_hollow}')
```

If you are using a version prior to Python 3.6, use the following:

```py
size = int(input(">"))
square = ''
square_with_hollow = ''

for i in range (0, size):
    square = '*' * size
    if i in (0, size -1):
        square_with_hollow = '*' * size
    else:
        square_with_hollow = '*{}*'.format(' ' * (size - 2))

    print('{} {}'.format(square, square_with_hollow))
```

Notice that this code will run faster than then one provided by @Psychoace. The complexity of this code is **O(n)**, while the complexity of the other code is **O(n ^ 2)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the filled one

```
def square():
    a = int(input(">"))
    for i in range(0, a):
        for j in range(1, a + 1):
            print ("# ", end = "")
        print()
    square()
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.